# iOS app crashing on iOS 7 only using Xcode 6.0.1 - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, xcode6

I'm getting into mobile app development and have been recently looking into mobile games. I stumbled across a Github Repo ([Here](https://github.com/kirualex/SprityBird)). It's a game built using SpriteKit which I'm trying to learn.

I tried to build and run it using Xcode 6.0.1 on an iPhone running iOS 7, and it crashed. It runs fine on devices running iOS 8. I added a breakpoint exception to try determine the cause of the crash and here is what I got:

```
2014-09-25 14:23:35.813 spritybird[4470:60b] -[Scene delegate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175de140
(lldb)
```

It seems to break on line 61 of the Scene.m file.

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(eventStart)]){ // This is line 61
   [self.delegate eventStart];
}
```

I can't seem to understand what is causing it to crash on iOS 7 only.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: does the eventStart method is accessed in the scope of this line ?

Comment: Which of those lines is line 61?

Comment: The first line is line 61.

Comment: Ok, I clarified that and upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Scene is most likely an `SKScene` subclass it doesn't acquire the `delegate` property (which is an instance of `SKSceneDelegate` till iOS8

So the code is wrong.

To fix at that point

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(delegate)]){
   if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(eventStart)]){
       [self.delegate eventStart];
   }
}
```

But really you want to dig into the code and work where `Scene` comes from and its inheritance to be sure as `eventStart` doesn't seem to be a `SpriteKit` framework symbol. Im guessing theres a bit of customisation of the delegate protocol too.

Comment: Thanks for you help Warren. I've tried it and it seems to break on the `ViewController.m` now: `scene.delegate` is declared as `self` (`scene.delegate = self;`). You're right, `Scene` is an `SKScene`subclass and it's declared in the Scene.h file. Xcode does show a warning in the Scene.h file: `/Users/Jason/Desktop/spritybird/Classes/Scenes/Scene.h:18:59: Property type 'id<SceneDelegate>' is incompatible with type 'id<SKSceneDelegate>' inherited from 'SKScene'`. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep - move on with learning things and forget about ios7 on this demo code for now. The warning basically says that SceneDelegate which is custom can't inherit from SKSceneDelegate.